# ggplot2 forcing histogram visuals to stay within certain breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a modification to my code which forces the plot to stay within my set breaks (which are purposefully quantiles of my datapoints).

```html
hist <- ggplot(df, aes(x = data)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5,breaks = quantile(df$data,seq(0,1,by = 0.2),na.rm = TRUE),binwidth = 2,colour = 9, fill = '#00C0B8') +
  labs(x = "xtitle", y = "Density", title = "title") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10000, by = 500));hist
```

Right now one or two outliers cause the visuals to stretch the plot immensely to fit the outliers.

[image]

Is there any argument to add that will stop this?

EDIT -----

This is what limit seemed to do, remove the last chunk of my histogram (it seems to remove that last chunk unless i include all the data points inside the limit argument) :

[image]

Comment: Especially without sample data (e.g., `dput(head(df,20))`), I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you mean to add `scale_x_continuous(breaks=..., limits=c(0,100)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=..., limits=c(0,10000))`?

Comment: does the limit argument remove data points from the histogram? I simply want the graph to visually cut off at (lets say 100) even though there are data points that exceed it. The goal of this particular histogram is to see 5 equal sized "buckets" of data points and when I have to see the random data point at 1500 while the majority of them are <100 it defeats the purpose of the plot

Comment: Try it. For example, compare `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()` and `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(15, 20))`.

Comment: @r2evans I added an edit to my post with the output including the limit argument. It seems to cut off my histogram prematurly. My ideal plot (if possible) would have that 0-100 limit with the last bucket starting from 20 and going off to the right

Comment: Okay, try instead with `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,10000))`, it works slightly differently (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67491822/3358272).

Comment: @r2evans worked exactly as I needed. Thanks a bunch!